# Gpu blinks when pressing power button, but computer won’t turn on at all

Tags: boot, gpu

Yesterday I reset my pc like 7 times trying to turn on secure boot in bios to play valorant. After playing for a few hours in secure boot, I shut it down and went to bed. Now when I try pressing the power button the gpu blinks and then nothing happens at all. I’m so lost and what I should do bc I tried some things online and nothing worked. I put a screwdriver to the cmos pins and waited 5 min, still nothing. I also replaced the cmos battery. Still nothing

I have an EVGA 500 BQ, Raedon 5600 XT, and a b450 Tomahawk Max MOBO.

Comment: Try starting with a bootable USB (any variety). If that does not work, take the machine to a local computer repair shop. Motherboard probably gone.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @John what is a bootable usb? Also, idk why the MOBO would be gone. I didn’t do anything to it, just shut it off for the night and then tried to turn it on the next morning.

Comment: Linux bootable USB, Windows ISO - you just want to see if it starts that way.

Comment: @John I have no way to create one because the only other computer I have had too old of a OS to download a media creation tool

Comment: Look at a Linux site and see if Rufus can create a bootable media.

Comment: Why are people suggesting Rufus?  The author cannot even boot into Windows.  I would even argue it sounds like the machine is not even POSTing.

Comment: It was only a test to see if the machine will start and if not get it serviced.

Comment: @John took it to best buy and they plug a new psu in it and it started. So just had to buy a new one. Still don’t understand why it went out though. Thank you for the help

Comment: i posted an answer for you and to summarize the situation.

Answer (score 0):

> I shut it down and went to bed. Now when I try pressing the power
> button the gpu blinks and then nothing happens at all.

You can try to troubleshoot by starting with a bootable USB key (which bypasses the main drive). Failure to start means you need to get the machine serviced.

> took it to best buy and they plug a new psu in it and it started. Still don’t understand why it went out though.

A power supply can fail for a variety of reasons:

Component failure: Capacitors (has been common), resistors, transistors, and voltage regulators.

Voltage regulators (LM317 or like) can be susceptible to overload or over voltage. If there was a power surge that could do it.

And good old fashion failures (tired components) can also occur.

That is a reasonable explanation as to Why?

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to see a machine where hitting the power button produced only a blip of power that wasn't a power supply problem.  Note that such supplies normally showed as ok with the usual power supply test devices.

What happens is that there is a failsafe system that ensures the power supply voltages are within tolerance and turns it off if they are not.  This failsafe is suppressed for a very short period when it's turned on as clearly it can't be producing the correct voltages when it's not yet producing any voltage other than the +5V standby power.

If the power supply fails to deliver enough power to satisfy all the components the voltage drops, the failsafe triggers and it turns off.  When the voltage fails to stabilize in time during startup you see a blip of light and fans turn a bit (although some have thermostats that keep them from spinning at all since the system is cold) and it shuts down.

The testers do not put enough load on the power supply and thus do not expose one that is weak but not completely dead.